# Validation in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I made an application to collect data from users.  Those data will be collected at different places and from these places will be sent to a central server.  I need to design a validation plan for the central server in PostgreSQL.  Data must be checked against various validations and if a validation fails a message must be thrown.

It is database to database transfer validation.

Comment: How do you want to send data from a DB to an other one?

Comment: @dezso: that is not my part .. I just have to do validation on central database . I dont know . Is there any possibility to check all fields against validation and throw error without coding in frontend ?

Comment: I am learning postgreSQL for this. But no idea how to implement this plan

Comment: I think I am getting it. I can to it with the help of trigger procedure http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html . If you have some better option please tell. Thank you

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes you're on the right track, you'll either use triggers and/or check constraints to do this.

Also, PostgresQL has a very flexible type system. Make sure to select the most appropriate, restrictive types. You can even define custom types yourself.

- [`UNIQUE` constraints](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#AEN2470)
- [`CHECK` Constraints](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#AEN2410)
- [`FOREIGN KEY` constraints](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) - [tutorial](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-fk.html)
- [Triggers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/triggers.html), which can call helper functions written in any supported procedural language. Triggers can `RAISE EXCEPTION` to abort a transaction.
- [Domain Types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/extend-type-system.html#AEN51665)
- [`EXCLUSION` constraints in 9.2 and newer](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION)
- Multi-column `PRIMARY KEY`s
- Partial `UNIQUE` indexes

Note that instead of using `varchar(length)` you're usually better off using `text` and a `check` constraint.

Comment: Thanks all.. I am able to make function and create trigger .

Comment: Why is using `text` and a check constraint usually better than `varcher(length)`?