# How to validate store accessor columns in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jsonb

We are using store_accessor, we could not validate store_accessor fields

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  store_accessor :data, :title, :user_id
  validates :title, uniqueness: true
end
```

We could not validate store_accessor column/field, we are facing pg error

Error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column accounts.title does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT  1 AS one FROM "accounts" WHERE "accounts"."title" = ...
```

Environment: **Ruby 2.4.1, Rails 5.1.4, PostgreSQL, Jsonb.**

How to use validation for store_accessor fields/ columns?

If we could not use default validate, how we could do custom validation for store_accessor fields?

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html This link mentions: **The default validations with the exception of uniqueness will work. For example, if you want to check for uniqueness with hstore you will need to use a custom validation to handle it.**

Comment: Thanks deep, how we could do store accessor validation.

Comment: @VtrKanna you can [set up validations on db side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12515021/validation-in-postgresql) or check manually via [exists?](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/exists%3f/class) and [SELECT ... FOR UPDATE](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html). Also if you want to validate hash you can use [dry-validation](http://dry-rb.org/gems/dry-validation/)