# Duplicate Records being Written to Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, duplicates

What could be the reason for duplicate records being written to the database days apart? In my create action, I first check if a record with a unique identifier exists, and updates it if it exists or else creates a new record. But right now in my database I'm seeing duplicate records that are not only seconds or minutes apart, but even days or months apart. What could be causing this?

```
def create
  record_uid = params.delete(:uid)

  if record_uid.present?
    record = Record.find_by(uid: record_uid)

    unless record.present?
      redirect_to error_path and return
    end
  else
    record = Record.new
  end

  record.attributes = params
  record.save

  redirect_to record
end
```

Comment: You must post more code for us to help.

Comment: is some part of code skipping validation?

Comment: db level constraint ?

Comment: Can be pretty much anything.

Comment: There is no validation in the model or constraint in the db. Shouldn't the create or update checking in the create action be enough? What could explain duplicate records days apart?

Comment: So to get this thing clear uniqueness of your record attributes depends on whether client passes `params[:id]` or not. Am I right?

Comment: It depends on a uid column that is separate from the id column.

Comment: Well yeah. `params[:uid]` then. So if client sends `params[:uid]` you update record and if it doesnt then you create one. Right? And in your dublicates `uid`s different and other attrs are dublicated?

Comment: Yes. And the uid is always included I can see it on the duplicates as well. The duplicates have the same uids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options:

1. Create db-level uniq constraint. Here is a [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12521563/4950680) that can help you. Based on your code I would suggest to create uniq btree index for uid column.
2. Create model-level uniq constraint with `ActiveModel` validations:

   ```
   class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
     validates :uid, uniqueness: true
   end
   ```

First option will raise `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` and on second `record.save` will return `false` so you need to handle that either way

Comment: Can something accidentally call `create` thru a GET? or is it only available as a POST?

Comment: The first one would raise an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique`, not simple return zero from `save`. But yeah, this is the way to go. You could even skip the validation and just deal with the exceptions (since you have to deal with them anyway) if you weren't expecting that many duplicates.