# Django with Postgres and advanced constraints

Tags: django, postgresql, constraints

I have the following model:

```
class AppHistory(models.Model):
    campaign = models.ForeignKey('campaigns.Campaign')
    context_tenant = models.ForeignKey('campaigns.FacebookContextTenant')
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

The backend is a Postgres database. For the above model I need the following constraints to be checked before a dataset is inserted:

- A row can only be inserted if it does not overlap in the date (`start_date` - `end_date`) with an existing one with the same `campaign` and `context_tenant`
- A row can only be inserted if there's none with the same `campaign` and `context_tenant` where `end_date` is NULL

I know there's the option to do this in Django by performing a validation.
But I'd like to make sure that even manual insertion into the database are verified.

So currently I came up with two options, database constraints and triggers. I'm not too familiar with postgres, so I'm uncertain how extensive the constraints are. Is it possible to do the above restrictions with constraints only or should I use triggers (or even something else)?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by using constraints, such as

```
EXCLUDE USING gist (campaign WITH =, daterange(start_date, end_date) WITH &&)
```

Comment: Please help me. Where did you put this constraint? In the model.py file, or through the shell. And in what way exactly? I'm struggling. Please help.

Comment: I managed to manually alter the database through PgAdmin4. Now I get the expected exception from postgres when I try to enter overlapping temporal values. How to deal with that in Django?

Answer (score 0):

you can use trigger in postgresql and RAISE EXCEPTION when data is invalid to roll back transaction
when you create your trigger you can use a custom migration to create trigger on database.
with migration.RunPython

Answer (score 0):

You should override  `save()` method in your model

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs): 

    <add your conditions here>  

    return super(AppHistory, self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

For your first condition where you want to check uniqueness you should use,

```
class Meta:  
    unique_together = ("campaign", "context_tenant", "start_date")
```

Comment: But everything in the save is only software base, menaing I can still `psql` and perform a manual INSERT to mess with the data, which I'm trying to prevent

Comment: okay, so have look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12515021/validation-in-postgresql